# vscode chrome developer tools console error on line 2586 how can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locale')
`uncaught type error at Object.7659 (content-script.js:2586:15513) at i (content-script.js:5297:7482) at content-script.js:5297:8843 at Function.i.O (content-script.js:5297:7752) at t (content-script.js:5297:8654) at vendors.js:2:91`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very very similar issue on my project. Finally found out it was a chrome extension that was causing the problem. For me it was Helium10, I deleted it and no more Error!